# Database Not Showing Data in Json Ajax

Tags: json, ajax

This is my view file `Book.cshtml` script section. The problem coming is that it not fetching my data from my database.
Instead it is giving a error:

> alert("Failed! Please try again.")

If I truncate the data from the database it shows ONLY the heading "BOOK ID" "BOOK NAME" "BOOK SERIAL NUMBER" "BOOK AUTHER" "BOOK PUBLISHER NAME"

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // This is for Get All Data
                $("#btnAllBook").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetAllBook","Books")",
                        data: "",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            loadData(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
                        }
                    });

                });
                // this will use for Get Data based on parameter
                $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetBookWithParameter", "Books")",
                        data: { prefix: $('#txtSearch').val() },
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            loadData(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
                        }
                    });
                });
                function loadData(data) {
                    // Here we will format & load/show data
                    var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
                    var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
                    thead.append('<th>Book ID</th>');
                    thead.append('<th>Book Name</th>');
                    thead.append('<th>Book Serial Number</th>');
                    thead.append('<th>Book Auther</th>');
                    thead.append('<th>Book Publisher</th>');
                    tab.append(thead);
                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        // Append database data here
                        var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
                        trow.append('<td>' + val.BookID + '</td>');
                        trow.append('<td>' + val.BookName + '</td>');
                        trow.append('<td>' + val.BookSerialNumber + '</td>');
                        trow.append('<td>' + val.BookAuther + '</td>');
                        trow.append('<td>' + val.BookPublisher + '</td>');
                        tab.append(trow);
                    });
                    $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
                    $("#UpdatePanel").html(tab);
                };
            });
```

Comment: Does the action methods define JsonBehavior.AllowGet, which is required to permit GET requests to return JSON?  Also, the error handler has a specific set of parameters that returns the actual error message, which is helpful...  Sometimes these errors are because it cannot reach the server or sometimes on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the documentation on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, the callback error is called because the request failed. Then, I suggest you to check if the url `@Url.Action("GetAllBook","Books")` is returning the right string of the url, maybe you are trying to request in a url that doesn't exists.

Another point, being about a GET request, I suggest you to check opening in a browser if this URL that you are trying to return data, is returning the JSON data expected as you need to append to the HTML.

Comment: the error i am getting is jquery-1.10.2.js:8720 GET http://localhost:60571/Book/Books 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8720
ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8150
(anonymous) @ Book:82
dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5109
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4780

Comment: Right, so the error is because this URL isn't returning nothing. You need to implement the endpoint /Book/Books to return the JSON data desired to get this data on AJAX request. So, you need to implement the Books action, i believe is the function Books, to return the JSON data needed.